# is it possible to return a generic struct with a random type from a function

Tags: generics, random, rust

I'm not certain what I want to do is possible but hopefully someone comes up with a solution. I have a struct:

```
pub struct VirtType<T> {
    value: T
}
```

And I want to generate a random value of a random type to fill this field like so:

```
pub fn random_type() -> VirtType {
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    match rng.gen_range(0,13) {
        0  => VirtType{value: rng.gen::<bool>()},                   //bool
        1  => VirtType{value: rng.gen::<u8>()},                     //u8
        2  => VirtType{value: rng.gen::<u16>()},                    //u16
        3  => VirtType{value: rng.gen::<u32>()},                    //u32
        4  => VirtType{value: rng.gen::<u64>()},                    //u64
        5  => VirtType{value: rng.gen::<u128>()},                   //u128
        6  => VirtType{value: rng.gen::<i8>()},                     //i8
        7  => VirtType{value: rng.gen::<i16>()},                    //i16
        8  => VirtType{value: rng.gen::<i32>()},                    //132
        9  => VirtType{value: rng.gen::<i64>()},                    //i164
        10 => VirtType{value: rng.gen::<i128>()},                   //i128
        11 => {                                                     //Array<T>
            let t = random_type();
            VirtType{value: (0..rng.gen_range(0,10)).map(|_| t.gen_another(&t)).collect()}
        },                                                          //Tuple(T)
        12 => VirtType{value: (0..rng.gen_range(2,10)).map(|_| random_type()).collect()},
        _  => panic!("Invalid number in random_type")
    }
}
```

I'm not the best with generics and, again, I feel like this is probably not going to work because there would be no way to know what the return type would be at compile time, but it would save me a BUNCH of redundancy. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: It is indeed impossible as is because `-> VirtType` misses the `<T>` (which would not be the same, depending on the branches of the `match`). But, assuming this would be possible, how would you plan to use the resulting `VirtType`? Without knowing exactly the intent, I guess an `enum` could help.

Comment: This is not possible, no. If you provide some more context about *why* you're doing this, someone might be able to propose a solution that accomplishes your underlying goal.

Comment: I concur, what you're asking for is strictly not possible, a Rust function can only return a single type so you'd have to either use an `enum` or use some sort of type erasure trick (and either downcasting or dynamic dispatch) to operate with it, but it would be very useful to know what this would be for, what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks everyone. i assumed as much. Im writing a code that randomly generates variables that can be easily converted to text. I was originally using enums but that lead to a bunch of massive match statements all over and all in all ended up just being sloppy. im currently trying to convert the code to use structs+traits instead of enums but i keep running into issues. heres a thread that goes into detail and asking for help on the main issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64495740/rust-trait-issues-trait-cannot-be-made-into-an-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pub struct VirtType<T> { ... }
pub fn random_type() -> VirtType { ... }
```

The most fundamental problem, the first place you should think "this can't work" is that you cannot omit a type parameter like this.

What you *can* do is eliminate the parameter with dynamic dispatch. Note that when you do so, you need to specify what you want to be able to do with the value, as a trait. You want to "convert them to text", so let's use `Debug`, but notice that you might well want to use a custom trait instead.

```
pub struct VirtType {
    value: Box<dyn Debug>
}
```

Now, we're going to construct these a lot, so let's define a helper method to avoid writing `VirtType { value: Box::new(...) }` a lot:

```
impl VirtType {
    fn new<T: 'static + Debug + Sized>(value: T) -> Self {
        VirtType { value: Box::new(value) }
    }
}
```

Now `random_type()` will compile if written like this:

```
pub fn random_type() -> VirtType {
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    match rng.gen_range(0,11) {
        0  => VirtType::new(rng.gen::<bool>()),
        1  => VirtType::new(rng.gen::<u8>()),
        2  => VirtType::new(rng.gen::<u16>()),
        3  => VirtType::new(rng.gen::<u32>()),
        ...
```

---

Now, there's some problematic cases remaining.

```
        11 => {                                                     //Array<T>
            let t = random_type();
            VirtType{value: (0..rng.gen_range(0,10)).map(|_| t.gen_another(&t)).collect()}
        },
```

To define `gen_another`, which I assume is supposed to produce more values of the same type (I'm not sure why it takes `t` both as self and a parameter), you'd need to use a custom trait instead of `Debug`, and give that trait a method which returns `Self`. But, you can't actually do that with dynamic dispatch ("trait objects")! Returning a value of unboxed dynamic type is not permitted.

You have two choices:

- Construct a vector of `VirtType` instances (but then you don't know they're all the same type).
- In the trait, write a method which returns a `VirtType` containing a vector of values.

```
        12 => VirtType{value: (0..rng.gen_range(2,10)).map(|_| random_type()).collect()},
```

This cannot work at all, at least if you mean to construct a real tuple: every possible tuple length is a different type. You'll need to return a vector, and if you want to make a distinction between heterogenous (tuple) and homogenous (vector/array), do it with an explicit marker of some sort.

Comment: `t.gen_another(&t)` was a mistake made when creating the minimal example, oops. youre correct in its usage though. and yeah the virtual "tuple" just constructs a vec of random VirtType. What you said here helped a LOT so thank you a ton. I'm about 90% of where i need to be now.

One last question though, do you know how i could go about setting up custom debug/display impl for each type contained within self.value? my end goal is to make VirtType display the type representation when printed in debug and the value when printed in display (eg debug: [u8;4] display: [33,8,25,4])

Comment: if you want more context about what i mean, [this this playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d89c2b77afcb5e6f4167ed066ad36989) is what im trying to condense down

Comment: @NoNameJones You would have to put your own formatting methods (like those on `Debug` and `Display`) on your custom trait that you're using in `dyn` if you follow my answer, and then you can have `VirtType` impl both `Debug` and `Display` and delegate the formatting to your custom methods.

Comment: oh perfect! thank you so much