# Is there a way to set the trait implemented struct to the struct field?

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to use trait variable without boxing it.

like the below, creating trait implemented struct instance without boxing is clear, but i cannot set this trait implemented instance to other struct's field.

I know using generic can solve this, (like `struct UserCertification\<T\> { current_work: T }` )
but I don' t want to use it.
Is there any other way to use trait implemented instance without boxing it?

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum Job { Teacher, Police }

trait Namable {
  fn name(&self) -> &'static str;
}

// Sample trait-implemented struct 1
struct TemporaryTeacher { }

impl Namable for TemporaryTeacher {
  fn name(&self) -> &'static str { "T.Teacher" }
}

// Sample trait-implemented struct 2
struct GeneralTeacher { }

impl Namable for GeneralTeacher {
  fn name(&self) -> &'static str { "G.Teacher" }
}

// Returns the instance wihtout Box.
fn create_named_object(job: Job, name: &str) -> impl Namable {
  TemporaryTeacher() // one of the result that implements trait Namable.
}

struct UserCertification {
  name: String,
  current_work: dyn Namable, // <- ERROR: cannot use dynamic directly. use Box<dyn Namable>.
}

fn main() {
  let named_object = create_named_object(Job::Teacher, "");
  let user = UserCertification("John", named_object);
}
```

I tried to find out how to create the instance without boxing process. To solve this problem, i searched and found using generic can handle this problem, but it is not an ideal solution.

Comment: This code does not need trait objects, so it should just use a generic. If you are doing something that requires trait objects, put it in your question.

Comment: Also you can't have a *trait object* not be behind some sort of pointer (reference, box, rc), that's just not possible as the compiler can't know the size of the underlying struct, and thus has no way set up its manipulation code.

Answer (score 0):

There are only three ways to do what you're trying in Rust. Each way has its own tradeoffs, so which is better will depend on your use case.

### Use a generic

```
trait Namable {}

struct UserCertification<T> {
    current_work: T,
}

impl<T: Namable> UserCertification<T> {
    fn new (current_work: T) -> Self {
        UserCertification { current_work, }
    }
}
```

This is probably the easiest way, and also the most efficient both in terms of memory used and of performance. The main drawback is that you can't mix multiple types in the same code, nor change the type stored in a variable on the fly:

```
struct Foo;
impl Namable for Foo {}
struct Bar;
impl Namable for Bar {}

// Impossible:
let v = vec![ UserCertification::new (Foo), UserCertification::new (Bar), ];

// Impossible too:
let mut v = UserCertification::new (Foo);
v = UserCertification::new (Bar);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5883a3e869cc4ab88bc3dff4be8789c1)

### Use a trait object

A trait object is written `dyn Namable` and it *must* be behind some kind of reference, e.g. `&dyn Namable`, `Box<dyn Namable>`, `Rc<dyn Namable>` or `Arc<dyn Namable>`.

```
trait Namable {}

struct UserCertification {
    current_work: Box<dyn Namable>,
}

impl UserCertification {
    fn new<T: Namable + 'static> (current_work: T) -> Self {
        UserCertification { current_work: Box::new (current_work), }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2c1dc2dee41626828acb717c03e2716d)

This is reasonably easy to use, allows a very wide range of uses including mixing different types and changing dynamically, but it's also the slowest of the three solutions. This is also the way most high-level languages do things (e.g. Java, Python, etc.). However [some traits cannot be made into trait objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64495740/5397009).

### Use an enum

```
trait Namable {
    fn name (&self) -> &'static str;
}

struct Foo;
impl Namable for Foo {
    fn name (&self) -> &'static str { "Foo" }
}
struct Bar;
impl Namable for Bar {
    fn name (&self) -> &'static str { "Bar" }
}

enum AllNamables {
    Foo (Foo),
    Bar (Bar),
}
impl Namable for AllNamables {
    fn name (&self) -> &'static str {
        match self {
            AllNamables::Foo (f) => f.name(),
            AllNamables::Bar (b) => b.name(),
        }
    }
}
impl From<Foo> for AllNamables {
    fn from (f: Foo) -> Self { AllNamables::Foo (f) }
}
impl From<Bar> for AllNamables {
    fn from (b: Bar) -> Self { AllNamables::Bar (b) }
}

struct UserCertification {
    current_work: AllNamables,
}

impl UserCertification {
    fn new<T: Into<AllNamables>> (current_work: T) -> Self {
        UserCertification { current_work: current_work.into(), }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7ff21b593f332adbd3c71db590e1f313)

This solution allows mixing different types and changing dynamically, it's also usually faster than the trait object solution on modern CPUs. But:

- It requires knowing all the possible types you need up front.
- It requires a lot of boilerplate (although crates like [`enum_dispatch`](https://crates.io/crates/enum_dispatch) may help there).

Comment: This is the answer exactly what i wanna get! sincerely appriciate your knowledge and thanks for your sharing.